# How to pass on a traceId from gRPC's context to another thread/threadPool?

Tags: multithreading, rx-java, grpc, hystrix, grpc-java

I am using grpc-java and have 3 services, A, B and C. I call service A and then service A calls B and C. I am using Hystrix in the calls to B and C. C in turn spawns another thread to call another service.

I have ClientInterceptors and ServerInterceptors which passes around the traceId. I can see the traceIds in the Context and logs as long as it is a gRPC worker thread but lose them when the call moves to another thread - RxIoScheduler thread or Hystrix thread. How do I pass the traceId around between requests on different threads and between different executor service and thread pools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is possible to propagate in a fine-grained way (like `executor.execute(Context.current().wrap(runnable))`), you should try to integrate `Context` propagation into cross-thread work transfer. For many applications, that'd be as simple as [wrapping the "main" executor](https://grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/Context.html#currentContextExecutor-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) as soon as it is created:

```
executor = Context.currentContextExecutor(executor);
// executor now auto-propagates
```

Do that once at the beginning of your application and then you mostly stop worrying about propagation.

But applications will vary. For example, applications that create `Thread`s directly should probably make a `ThreadFactory` that propagates the calling thread's `Context` to the `Thread`:

```
class PropagatingThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
  private final ThreadFactory delegate;

  public PropagatingThreadFactory(ThreadFactory d) {delegate = d;}

  @Override public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
    return delegate.newThread(Context.current().wrap(r));
  }
}
```

Comment: how can I propagate context when I dont explicitly create executor in my application?

Comment: gRPC propagates Context for callbacks, independent of whether using the default Executor built into gRPC Channels/Servers. For your own executor-based logic, you can wrap an Executor even if you didn't create it. If you can't do that either, then worst-case you can always [wrap each individual Runnable](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/Context.html#wrap-java.lang.Runnable-) as you pass it to the Executor.

Comment: I am facing issues in accessing gRPC context in client interceptor. I am setting some headers in server interceptor and trying to access the same in client interceptor but I cant due to ThreadLocal. Should I still deal with executor or try some other approach? I very new to this so trying to understand flow.

Comment: @AkashShinde, clarify what you are doing in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70151106/grpc-use-of-contextpropagatingexecutorservice-and-currentcontextexecutor and we'll discuss there.