# gRPC - Use of ContextPropagatingExecutorService and currentContextExecutor

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

Since gRPC makes service call on new thread and gRPC context is Thread Local, how can I propagate this gRPC context? I found that Context.currentContextExecutor() and ContextPropagatingExecutorService can be used but I haven't found enough resources or example for these 2 options. Can someone help to implement these?

Comment: @eric-anderson any idea about this?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. You start with "since" but talk about things that the gRPC implementation has to deal with, not you. Where do you want to propagate the context from and to?

Comment: @EricAnderson I have backend service, client interceptor and server interceptor. Call to gRPC stub is made using Future.callback method which creates new thread. The response is on new thread which doesnt have context from server. I want to access gRPC server context in grpc client.  To summarise, I want to set some headers in grpc server and access them in client interceptor via Context. Currently I am getting null when I try to access Context variable.

Answer (score 1):

ClientInterceptors shouldn't change the context instance seen by the application. The Context behavior shouldn't really change whether using blocking, async, or future stubs and a blocking API would not be able to change the current context.

While an interceptor is free to modify a pre-existing (mutable) value in the Context, there's generally little need. It is normally easier to create a new interceptor instance each RPC and communicate with the interceptor directly, or communicate via a custom CallOption.

If you have just a single call site that needs access to response headers, then [`MetadataUtils.newCaptureMetadataInterceptor()`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/stub/MetadataUtils.html#newCaptureMetadataInterceptor-java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference-java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference-) is a convenient (although roundabout) way to get the Metadata. It was designed for testing, but is appropriate for small-scale use outside of testing situations.

```
AtomicReference<Metadata> headers = new AtomicReference<>();
AtomicReference<Metadata> trailers = new AtomicReference<>();
// Using blocking for simplicity, but applies equally to futures
stub.withInterceptors(MetadataUtils.newCaptureMetadataInterceptor(headers, trailers))
    .someRpc();
Metadata headersSeen = headers.get();
```

If you need to access the same header from multiple callsites, it is better to create a custom interceptor that does what you need.

```
CustomInterceptor interceptor = new CustomInterceptor();
stub.withInterceptors(interceptor)
    .someRpc();
... = interceptor.getWhateverValue();
```

This is demonstrating a "general" use case. Specific instances commonly can tweak their API further to be more convenient and natural.